# How to remove 'io.card' from Cordova/payPal SDK

Tags: android, cordova, paypal

I am building Android app with cordova on windows PC and I have been trying to remove 'io.card' from my payPal cordova sdk in order to reduce the size of my apk; but to no avail.

I have read their manual about [Disabling Direct Credit Card Payments](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK#disabling-direct-credit-card-payments) by including

```
`dependencies {
     compile('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.1') {
        exclude group: 'io.card'
      }
 }`
```

in "MY" build.gradle file. They did not show the location of the build.gradle file that should be modified. However I managed to find a build.gradle file under "PROJECT_FOLDER/platforms/android/" However, when I add the

`compile('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.1') {
        exclude group: 'io.card'
      }`

But when I do a new build (cordova run) the dependencies gets removed and therefore the size of my application remains 33.6MB instead of 17.6MB.

I have also seen [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38887998/paypal-is-not-working-after-removing-io-card/38888380?noredirect=1#comment70204924_38888380) But the answer is not clear to me.

I will be glad if someone can show me what I am doing wrong, or not doing right. Thank you

This is the link to my build.gradle file -> [build.gradle](https://gist.github.com/philecom/bc9c5fcd3c2f713600a8128677293601)

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan I have update the post with a link to my build.gradle file.
https://gist.github.com/philecom/bc9c5fcd3c2f713600a8128677293601